# Sorting an array when values are decreased by each swap

Tags: algorithms, sorting, array

Recently in an interview I come across a question:

> We have an unsorted array, we need to sort it with minimum number of swap. We have in sort a 'tax' of 1 is deducted from the number we are swapping.

so suppose initially we have an array as

```
2 4 1 3 5
^   ^
```

on swaping say 2 and 1, the new state of the array is:

```
0 4 1 3 5  // 'tax' of 1 is deducted from 1 and 2 
^   ^      // so we have 0 and 1 at there place after the swap
```

So we need to sort the array in min. number of swap. Any suggestions regarding the algorithm design?

I thought of doing this with merger sort but still not sure if this is the best approach.

Comment: Have you seen http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Comparison_of_algorithms

Comment: Yes obviously i do :P but point is if u ll be using merge sort or quick they will be first dividing array and then will be swaping obviously on swap value of element will be altered and then you can not ensure weather you had chosen right pivot or the merging will still give a correct result

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner : thanks for guidance though

Comment: Well that's the thing: Quicksort has the *potential* to perform poorly. If you read the detailed analysis it depends on the choice of pivot, and possibly the state of the input array. Similarly, executing Mergesort on the same array may result in a different number of swaps if the input array is re-arranged for each execution.

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner : well that's what exactly the problem  is merger sort won't perform and chosing a random pivot is still not a good choice :) in this case

Comment: The only Correct answer is "I don't know if you want me to solve it for best, worst or typical case, I have no idea of the expected input data - size, range, distribution. Does the array have repeated elements or not?".  

Their answer to this question would determine how quickly I ran for the door.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe that applying an existing sorting algorithm will help much.  In your example, I believe the minimum number of swaps is 2:

```
2 (4) (1) 3 5 -> 2 0 3 3 5
(2) (0) 3 3 5 -> -1 1 3 3 5
```

This happens to fit the profile of a bubble sort, but that algorithm takes 7 steps to solve "5 4 3 2 1", which an insertion sort can handle in 2 steps:

```
(5) 4 3 2 (1) -> 0 4 3 2 4
0 (4) 3 (2) 4 -> 0 1 3 3 4
```

There are also situations where you can find multiple distinct solutions to the same problem:

```
2 4 1 5 3
2 4 1 2 4
2 1 1 3 4
0 1 1 3 4
```

or

```
2 4 1 5 3
2 4 1 3 3
2 0 3 3 3
-1 1 3 3 3
```

Answer (score 2):

Note that the task is to optimize *the number of swaps*, not the number of comparisons. For standard sorting, it should be obvious that simple "selection sort" does not need more than n-1 swaps, so I guess this modified problem won't need more swaps in general.

Here a first try:

- Loop through the array until you find a number which is smaller than the one before (lets say at the index i). If there is none, the array is sorted and you can stop
- find the smallest element in the subarray a[i],...,a[n], lets say a[j]
- swap a[j] with the first element from a[1],...,a[i-1] which is bigger than a[j] (lets say a[k]. Since a[k] must be greater than a[k-1] (or k=1), swapping won't destroy the existing order of a[1],...,a[i-1]. Note that there must be such an element, since a[k]>a[i]>=a[j] for every k

  repeat these steps until the array is sorted

I admit, I am not sure if this will always produce the minimum number of swaps, still trying to find a proof (or a counterexample). But lets make some examples:

```
5 4 3 2 1    -> 1 is the smallest beyond 5: swap with 5
0 4 3 2 4    -> 2 is the smallest beyond 4: swap with 4
0 1 3 3 4
```

or your original example:

```
2 4 1 3 5  ->  1 is the smallest beyond 4: swap with 2
0 4 1 3 5  ->  1 is the smallest beyond 4: swap with 4
0 0 3 3 5
```

If someone finds a counterexample, showing that this algorithm is not optimal, please don't hesitate to present it.

Comment: Thanks alot i foound this the most suitable explanation of the problem so far :) . Bad i can not even up vote the answer :(. still thanks a tone for ur suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Hi After thinking a bit i came across this solution and now i am feeling like i was avoiding a very basic concept.
SO i implement sorting through merger sort , which basically divides and sort and merger the array . we have tax is deducted for swaping two values but not for comparision .

so I used an alternate array temp in order to merge the values and then copy the value of the same into the original array my C++ code is something like this :

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

void merge(int a[],int temp[],int left,int mid,int right);

void mergesort(int a[],int temp[],int low,int high)
{
    int mid;
    if(low < high ){

        mid=(int)(high+low)/2;
        mergesort(a,temp,low,mid);
        mergesort(a,temp,mid+1,high);
        merge(a,temp,low,mid+1,high);
    }
}

void merge(int a[],int temp[],int left,int mid,int right)
{
    int i,left_end,size,temp_pos;
    left_end=mid-1;
    size=right-left+1;
    temp_pos=left;
    while((left <= left_end) && (mid<=right)){
        if(a[left]<=a[mid]){
            temp[temp_pos]=a[left];
            temp_pos=temp_pos+1;
            left=left+1;
        }
        else{
            temp[temp_pos]=a[mid];
            mid=mid+1;
            temp_pos=temp_pos+1;
        }
    }

    while(left<=left_end)
    {
        temp[temp_pos]=a[left];
        left=left+1;
        temp_pos=temp_pos+1;
    }

    while(mid<=right)
    {
        temp[temp_pos]=a[mid];
        mid=mid+1;
        temp_pos=temp_pos+1;
    }

    for(int i=0;i<=size;i++){
        a[right]=temp[right];
        right=right-1;
    }
}

int main(){
    int a[]={5,4,9,8,7,1,2,0,3,6};
    int temp[10];
    mergesort(a,temp,0,9);
    for(int i=0;i<=9;i++)
        cout<<a[i];
    return 0;
}
```

Any suggestion regarding the same is appreciated i would love to know feedback regarding my approach .